# Extract class with imported classes in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, class

My problem is that I want to isolate a class of a really big project and extract it into a clean new project to perform benchmarking. Obviously I need all the classes that it imports as well (and also the classes that *they* import), especially for easy reintegration later on.

Is there a way in eclipse to copy the class with all the necessary imported classes? Or show all classes that are not needed for the current class with the main function? Maybe a script or plugin? How would you do this?

Comment: This sounds like a frustrating exercise.  What about just adding the existing project as a dependency of your benchmarking project, and just leaving all its classes right where they are?

Comment: I recommend instead of copying the class into another project, either create a test class in the same package of the required class and test from that class (Inside you current project) OR, create a new project and import your project into the new project. Edit: Sniped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no easy way. If your project is big and complicated it's also likely that your class depends on a lot more other classes than you expect.
Do the benchmarking within the project you have or create an empty benchmarking project than depends on your big project and imports the classes you're analysing.